# Existential types in Scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

Please find below a short example which puzzles me.

I must concede that I have some difficulties to manipulate existential types in Scala.

How should I solve the type mismatch line 56 ?
proposer is OK type _$1 while proposers is of type _$1 <: Individual

Thanks in advance,

### Maxime.

```
class Individual(n: String) {
  protected val name=n
  var preferred: Individual = this
  override def toString(): String=name
}

class Man(n: String) extends Individual(n) { }

class Woman(n: String) extends Individual(n) { }

class Marriage(m: Man, w: Woman){
  private val man=m
  private val woman=w
  def this(w: Woman, m: Man) = this(m,w)
  override def toString(): String = man+"--"+woman
}

class Matching(){
  private var list: List[Marriage] = Nil
  def add(m: Marriage): Unit = { list = m ::list }
  override def toString(): String= {
    var s: String = ""
    for (elm<-list) s=s+elm+" "
    return s
  }
}

object Test{
  protected var male = true

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val al      = new Man("Al")
    val bob     = new Man("Bob")
    val alice   = new Woman("Alice")
    val barbara = new Woman("Barbara")

    al.preferred      = alice
    bob.preferred     = barbara
    alice.preferred   = bob
    barbara.preferred = al

    val men   = Set(al, bob)
    val women = Set(alice, barbara)

    val m = new Matching()
    //var proposers=women

    var proposers: Set[_ <:Individual] = Set[Individual]()
    if (male) proposers = men
    else proposers = women

    while (!proposers.isEmpty) {
      for(proposer <- proposers) {
        val proposer=proposers.head
        if (proposer.isInstanceOf[Man])
          m.add(new Marriage(
            proposer.asInstanceOf[Man],
            proposer.preferred.asInstanceOf[Woman]
          )) 
        else 
          m.add(new Marriage(
            proposer.asInstanceOf[Woman],
            proposer.preferred.asInstanceOf[Man]
          ))
        proposers-=proposer//There is an error here
      } 
    }

    println(m)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Can you explicitly mention what you did not understand above.

Comment: How to solve the type mismatch line 56 ? Any idea ?

Comment: Can you comment in your code where there is an error

Comment: List which is covariant must be preferred to Set which is not. Therefore, I use var proposers: List[Individual] = List[Individual]() and proposers=proposers.filterNot(p=>p==proposer). It works.

Comment: "works" is a strong statement, all you did was resolve the compilation error.  To truly *work* it must also be maintainable, which means you must progress beyond simply writing Java with inference.

Comment: It's probably today's political climate, but this feels like an awfully loaded question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is messy.  It's poorly formatted, it mixes tabs and spaces, and it uses mutability even in the most trivial of places where a functional solution requires little thought.

This code also won't scale internationally to countries where same-sex marriage is a possibility.

Working from the top down...

I suspect you'll *never* want to directly instantiate an `Individual`, only ever a `Man` or a `Woman`.  So a algebraic data type makes more sense, this is done with a `sealed trait` and `case class` subtypes.

I'll also drop the `preferred` property, as it can lead to circular references.  Dealing with this in immutable data is beyond the level I'm willing to go in this answer.

```
sealed trait Individual {
  def name: String
  override def toString(): String=name
}

//as it's a case class, `name` becomes a val,
//which implements the abstract `def name` from the trait
case class Man(name: String) extends Individual

case class Woman(name: String) extends Individual
```

`Marriage` can also be a case class, and let's drop the clumsy duplication of class parameters into vals - it's just pointless boilerplate.  This is also a good time to move the auxiliary constructor to a factory method in the companion object:

```
case class Marriage(man: Man, woman: Woman) {      
  override def toString(): String = man + "--" + woman
}
object Marriage {
  def apply(w: Woman, m: Man) = new Marriage(m,w)
}
```

`Matching` is almost pointless, an entire class just to wrap a `List`?  This kind of thing made sense in pre-Generics Java, but not any more.  I'll keep it anyway (for now) so I can fix up that `toString` implementation, which is painfully mutable and uses `return` for no good reason:

```
case class Matching(){
  private var list: List[Marriage] = Nil
  def add(m: Marriage): Unit = { list ::= m }
  override def toString() = list.mkString(" ")
}
```

Finally, the "meat" of the problem.  Comments are inline, but you'll note that I don't need (or use) `Matching`.  It's replaced in its entirety by the final `println`

```
object Test{
  //better name, and a val (because it never changes)
  protected val menPropose = true

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // `new` not required for case classes
    val al      = Man("Al")
    val bob     = Man("Bob")
    val alice   = Woman("Alice")
    val barbara = Woman("Barbara")

    // remember how preference was removed from `Individual`?
    val mprefs = Map( al -> alice, bob -> barbara )
    val fprefs = Map( alice -> bob, barbara -> al )

    val men   = Set(al, bob)
    val women = Set(alice, barbara)

    // nicely immutable, and using the returned value from if/else
    val proposers = if (menPropose) men else women

    // no while loop, name shadowing, or mutability.
    // just a simple for-comprehension
    val marriages = for(proposer <- proposers) yield {
      //pattern-matching beats `isInstanceOf`... every time
      proposer match {
        case m: Man => Marriage(m, mprefs(m))
        case f: Woman => Marriage(f, fprefs(f))
      }
    }

    println(marriages mkString " ")
  }
}
```

There's more that can be done here, way more.  What of same-sex relationships?  What if two or more people share the same preference?  What if someone has no preference?

I could also encode the type of someone's preference into `Individual` instances.  But that's getting a bit more advanced.